# provides incorrect result while passing run time parmer

Tags: python

I am trying to write a if elif condition in python to compare the input value and provide the result set but it always go to else condition for valid values also .

```
import sys
firstarg=sys.argv[1].strip()
print firstarg
if firstarg == 1:
    print 'A'
elif firstarg == 2:
    print 'B'
elif firstarg == 3:
    print 'C'
elif firstarg == 4:
   print 'D'
else:
    print 'End'
```

Output :-

```
#>sample.py 4
4
End

#>sample.py 3
3
End

#>sample.py 2
2
End
```

can you help me in fixing the issue

Comment: You're comparing a string to numbers. `"1" == 1` will always be False.

Comment: `firstarg=sys.argv[0].strip()` : You compare rootpath of the script against a integer... euhm...

Comment: Remove `print firstarg` (3rd line) and see the ouput. Only `END` will be  printed since all conditions are false each time.

Answer (score 1):

You mostly face these type of issues if you are comparing different data types.
Check the data type of `firstarg` by `print type(firstarg)`.  It will be `string` in this case and you are comparing it with an integer.

So, either typecast firstarg to int(firstarg) before comparing or compare with 1,2,3,4 as strings like `if firstarg == '1'` .

Answer (score 0):

To be honest... the code throws a traceback error and nobody mentions this in comments. Its a "list index out of range...".

Here is something that works and helps understand what goes on with your code (see inline comments too).

```
import sys

#firstarg=sys.argv[0].strip()

filepath = 'D:\\Test\\bingo1.py'       # set an example filepath with random filename.

firstarg=filepath.split('.')       # split filepath -> 2 list items: 'filename', 'extension'].

print firstarg, type(firstarg)

firstarg = firstarg[0][-1]         # see if the last character in the string is an integer

print firstarg, type(firstarg)

firstarg = int(firstarg)           # convert string to integer.

if firstarg == 1:
    print 'A'
elif firstarg == 2:
    print 'B'
elif firstarg == 3:
    print 'C'
elif firstarg == 4:
   print 'D'
else:
    print 'End'
```

Output:

> `['D:\\Test\bingo1', 'py'] <type 'list'>`
>
> `1 <type 'str'>`
>
> `A`

Enjoy ;-)